# I want to write a function to check the fontsize scaling to stop being bigger when the font size reaches 60, and also it should not be smaller than 8

Tags: flutter, dart

````
 ``` class _StructStyleState extends State<StructStyle> {
          double _prevScale;
          double _scale;

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _prevScale = _scale = 1.0;
          }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
                setState(() {
                  _scale = (_prevScale * (details.scale));
                });
              },
              onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
                setState(() {
                  _prevScale = _scale;
                });
              },
````

want to a  function to check the fontsize scaling to stop being bigger when the font size reaches 60, and also it should not be smaller than 8

````
Body:Text(
                           "hyira nka beae no, ofi no, "

                             style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 20 * _scale,
                             fontFamily: "NotoSans",
                             ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                           ),```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly
why don't you write something like this

```
fontSize: (20 * _scale).clamp(8.0, 60.0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked when I changed the fontfamily and used fontsize(20*_scale).clamp(8.0, 60.0)

Comment: if this solves the question, mark it as the answer please